# selenium element data extract

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've this type of page

```
<body>
<p> This is a demo page </P>
<div id=1>
<div>
<p>hii hiidbvsvdvif </P>
<p>hii hiidbvsvdvif </P>
<p>hii hiidbvsvdvif </P>
<p>hii hiidbvsvdvif </P>
<p>hii hiidbvsvdvif </P>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

i use selenium to existing. But I can't get my results

```
driver.find_element_by_id("1")
```

**i need same output like this : All "p" tag and "div" tag as it is same**

```
<div id="1">
<div>
<p>hii hiidbvsvdvif </P>
<p>hii hiidbvsvdvif </P>
<p>hii hiidbvsvdvif </P>
<p>hii hiidbvsvdvif </P>
<p>hii hiidbvsvdvif </P>
</div>
</div>
```

**anyone please help me**

Comment: add the html with the tree structure vsible  now it looks like everything in same level

Answer (score 0):

if div is child if div with id 1 and p is child of this element then use :

```
words =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id=\"1\"]//p")
for word in words:
    print(word.text)
```

sometimes text won't work if the text is not visible in UI ( if its not in view of screen)

you need to use getAttribute("textContent")

```
words =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id=\"1\"]//p")
for word in words:
    print(word.getAttribute("textContent"))
```

Comment: But , webpage sometimes change structure. Like <div> <ul> <li> <p> etc. So now I need to get all child elements. How can i get ?

Comment: Changed it to //p